# SXA Filter API ignore the custom index

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet, index

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I've created custom index for my site and it's working fine, the SXA OOB Search results API is using the custom index which is right
[image]

But the SXA OOB Search filters API is still using the default index
[image]

Is there is specific configuration for the filter API

Comment: It should use the same index in both cases and it works like that on the latest code. I don't remember right now it we had such issue registered in the past. Please contact Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks @DawidRutkowski, I'll contact Sitecore Support.